# Perform loop in HPC within multiple subdirectories one after another

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, recursive

I know this is a repeated question, but none of the suggestions I saw kinda fit what I wanted.

I'm working with an HPC cluster that has different modules to perform different actions for high throughput data. Previously I've been successful using the following piece of code to perform actions on a series of files within a directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

module load random_module

fqFiles=`find $1 -name '*.nii' -type f`

for fqFile in $fqFiles;do
some random action
done
```

However I'd like to perform some more complex actions involving more files and performing them over multiple subfolders.

Each subfolder belongs to different specimens with different IDs and contains a number of files that reflect the ID of the specimen (which changes based on the name of the specimen).

The action that needs to be performed inside each subfolder is:

```
eddy --main=ID.nii \
--mask=ID_mask.nii \
--index=ID_index.txt \
--acqp=ID_acqp.txt \
--bvecs=ID.bvec \
--bvals=ID.bval \
--fwhm=0 \
--flm=quadratic \
--out=eddy_out \
--data_is_shelled
```

Where "ID" changes based on the ID of the specimen to be analysed. Subfolder "specimen1" is called like that, and contains files `specimen1.nii`, `specimen1_mask.nii`, `specimen1_index.txt`, etc, and this is the same for all the 50 specimens to be analysed. The problem is that all specimens have different names, like "Mike", "Charles", "Anita", etc, so it's nothing sequential or numerical.

Could anyone help me wrapping this up in a script that performs the action on one folder and then moves to the next to perform the same action on the next subfolder despite having different subfolder names and file prefixes?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: To confirm, you have directories named Mike, Charles, Anita etc, and in each directory, you have files named Mike...nii, Mike...txt, Charles...nii etc. You need to run `eddy --main=Mike.nii --mask=Mike_mask.nii ...` etc. on all these directories. One `eddy` invocation per directory. Is that correct?

Comment: Possible solution: `for SPEC in Mike Charles Anita; do cd $SPEC; eddy --main=${SPEC}.nii --index=${SPEC}_mask.nii ....; cd ..; done` (I didn't write out the entire `eddy` command)

Comment: Hi @berndbausch Yes, that is correct. One invocation of eddy per specimen which uses all those different files in the subdirectory to work. The files have the name of the specimen as prefix. Do you have to write all the names of the specimens after `for SPEC in` ? Or can you make a list of all the subdirectories and then feed them one by one to the loop? I have 50 specimens... Thanks for your time!

Comment: The list after `for SPEC in` can be generated automatically. However I don't have enough information about the directory structure to tell you what exactly to do. For example, are there only specimen directories under the top directory? Or other files and directories? If there is more than just specimens, only you can compile the correct list. Another question: Do the specimen directories have subdirectories? If you added partial output of the `tree` command to your question, that would be helpful. You may have to install `tree` first.

Comment: Hi @berndbausch. Thanks for your help, I'll give more details now. The directory where I will call this script *only* has one subdirectory per specimen (50 subdirectories in total), and those subdirectories only have the files I need for the analysis. No more subdirectories or any other file that is not strictly required for the analysis as per the original script. I'm trying to keep things as tidy as possible to simplify the writing of the script. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With your additional information, I am fairly confident the following is a solution:

```
for SPEC in * 
do 
    cd "$SPEC" 
    eddy --main="${SPEC}.nii" \
         --mask="${SPEC}_mask.nii" \
         --index="${SPEC}_index.txt" \
         --acqp="${SPEC}_acqp.txt" \
         --bvecs="${SPEC}.bvec" \
         --bvals="${SPEC}.bval" \
         --fwhm=0 --flm=quadratic --out=eddy_out --data_is_shelled
    cd ..
done
```

**Dicussion**

I replaced your ID with SPEC, for "specimen" (feel free to call it anything you like). The `*` generates the list of all specimen subdirectories, and the `for` loop assigns them to variable `SPEC`, one after the other.

Since the directory names may have funny characters in them that could be interpreted by the shell, all references to `SPEC` are in double quotes. This removes the interpretation of special characters except the dollar.

So for each `SPEC`, we enter the subdirectory, run the `eddy` command and go back up to the parent directory.`{SPEC}` is written like that since the underscore in `SPEC_mask` etc. would otherwise be interpreted as part of the variable name. Since variable names can't include dots, `"$SPEC.nii"` would work, but I leave the `{ }` in for consistency.

Comment: Most appreciated =) I'll try this in the next few days.